# React - Redux add item to current state using action creator

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to add more items to current state inside reducer, but not getting desired results.

My books reducers

```
export default function() {
  return[
    {title: 'Abc'},
    {title: 'Def'},
    {title: 'Ghi'},
    {title: 'Jkl'}
  ]
}
```

Add book reducer

```
export default function(state='', action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_BOOK':
    console.log(action.payload);
    return [
      ...state,
      state.books.push({'title':'giki'})
    ]
    default:
    return state
  }
  return state;
}
```

code for combining reducers

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  books: BooksReducer,
  addBook: AddBookReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and finally inside container

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    books: state.books
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({addBook: addBook}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

In the console, I am getting

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Can someone help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the default state has no books array. Try creating a default state like `defaultState = { books: [] }` and then update your book reducer with `export default function(state = defaultState, action){...}`

EDIT:
Looking further at your questions the whole books state is an array so I don't think the above will work. Try changing the 7th line in your reducer to `state.push({'title':'giki'})`

Comment: You need state to be an object with a property called books that is an array.

Comment: can you elaborate plz

Comment: Like this: `state = { books: [] }`